# dovecot my emails are disappearing even though quota is disabled

Tags: email, cpanel, dovecot, quota

I have a dovecot mailserver running on CentOS. I use CPanel to manage it. The problem is all mail in my sent folder keeps disappearing as if a quota was met but quotas are set to no limit in CPanel .

I cant find any setting in Thunderbird that is causing the mail to be deleted.

Versions are:

- *Dovecot*: 2.2.26
- *CentOS*: 6.8 64
- *CPanel* auto update to 60.0.28

I have attached the log section that shows Dovecot's configuration for the sales account removing any major identifiers other than UIDs

```
    Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: auth input: tony@domain.com gid=514 quota_vsizes=yes mail=maildir:/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony quota_rule2=INBOX.Trash:ignore quota_rule=*:messages=2147483647 quota_status_overquota=552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full / Blocks limit exceeded / Inode limit exceeded uid=502 home=/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony quota=maildir:Mailbox:ns=INBOX. quota_clone_dict=file:/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony/dovecot-quota quota2=fs:cPanel Account
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=maildir:Mailbox:ns=INBOX.
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota2=fs:cPanel Account
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_clone_dict=file:/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony/dovecot-quota
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule=*:messages=2147483647
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_rule2=INBOX.Trash:ignore
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_status_overquota=552 5.2.2 Mailbox is full / Blocks limit exceeded / Inode limit exceeded
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota_vsizes=yes
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Effective uid=502, gid=514, home=/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota root: name=Mailbox backend=maildir args=ns=INBOX.
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=Mailbox mailbox=* bytes=0 messages=2147483647
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota rule: root=Mailbox mailbox=INBOX.Trash ignored
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota grace: root=Mailbox bytes=0 (10%)
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota root: name=cPanel Account backend=fs args=
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Quota grace: root=cPanel Account bytes=0 (10%)
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=INBOX., sep=., inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony, alt=
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: fs quota add mailbox dir = /home/domain/mail/domain.com/tony
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: fs quota block device = /dev/mapper/server-home
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: fs quota mount point = /home
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: fs quota mount type = ext4
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: Namespace : type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=no, hidden=yes, list=no, subscriptions=no location=fail::LAYOUT=none
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: none: root=, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: STORAGE ret=0 value=1466375 limit=0
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: MESSAGE ret=1 value=33527 limit=2147483647
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag=0((null)) vs currently overquota=0
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag check: STORAGE ret=0 value=112694708 limit=0
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965, tony@domain.com): Debug: quota: quota_over_flag=0((null)) vs currently overquota=0
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox <lmtp DATA>: Opened mail UID=1 because: copying
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(tony@domain.com): 0WZxxxxxxxxxxAAT/Rueg: msgid=<000401d25xxxxxxxxxx350$f5da09f0$@z-xxxxxxxx.se>: saved mail to INBOX
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: access
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: access
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: access
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: access
Dec  9 09:37:57 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX: Opened mail UID=96234 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:29 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: quota: No quota setting - plugin disabled
Dec  9 09:38:29 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: The quota_clone_dict setting is missing from configuration
Dec  9 09:38:29 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: none: root=, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
Dec  9 09:38:29 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Connect from local
Dec  9 09:38:29 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
Dec  9 09:38:33 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: 6/14 headers not cached (first=BCC) (Mail has other cached fields, reset_id=1473431747)
Dec  9 09:38:33 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:33 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:33 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:34 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:34 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:34 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5049 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:35 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: 7/14 headers not cached (first=BCC) (Mail has other cached fields, reset_id=1473431747)
Dec  9 09:38:35 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:35 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:35 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.1A responded: Opened mail UID=5050 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.Sent: Opened mail UID=2275 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.Sent: Opened mail UID=2275 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:39 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.Sent: Opened mail UID=2275 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:44 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.eBay Junk: Opened mail UID=20246 because: prefetch
Dec  9 09:38:44 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.eBay Junk: Opened mail UID=20246 because: access
Dec  9 09:38:44 server dovecot: imap(tony@domain.com): Debug: Mailbox INBOX.eBay Junk: Opened mail UID=20246 because: full mail
Dec  9 09:38:50 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: quota: No quota setting - plugin disabled
Dec  9 09:38:50 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: The quota_clone_dict setting is missing from configuration
Dec  9 09:38:50 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Debug: none: root=, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
Dec  9 09:38:50 server dovecot: lmtp(12965): Connect from local
```

exim_mainlog

```
    2016-12-19 12:24:51 [45169] 1cIwzq-000BkX-M8 <= customer@msn.com H=col004-omc1s19.hotmail.com [65.55.34.29]:64183 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=no S=30328 M8S=0 id=VI1PR0201MB24464062E4CCC64AEB63FC4C98910@VI1PR0201MB2446.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <customer@msn.com> for returns@domain.com
2016-12-19 12:24:51 [45180] 1cIwzq-000BkX-M8 => returns <returns@domain.com> F=<customer@msn.com> P=<customer@msn.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery S=31131 C="250 2.0.0 <returns@domain.com> xuhAIZPRV1iAsAAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=1s DT=0s
2016-12-19 12:24:51 [45180] 1cIwzq-000BkX-M8 Completed QT=1s

2016-12-21 14:03:23 [45603] 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 <= sales@domain.com H=host81-149-113-123.in-addr.btopenworld.com (CI352561) [81.149.113.123]:56132 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:email@domain.com S=238704 M8S=0 id=10379473.175.1482328989231.JavaMail.GeoCust@CI352561 T="Your Order - Invoice 260054" from <sales@domain.com> for customer@msn.com sales@domain.com
2016-12-21 14:03:23 [45606] 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 SMTP connection outbound 1482329003 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 domain.com customer@msn.com
2016-12-21 14:03:23 [45606] 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 => sales <sales@domain.com> F=<sales@domain.com> P=<sales@domain.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery_no_batch S=241978 C="250 2.0.0 <sales@domain.com> uQZlEauLWlgrsgAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=3s DT=0s
2016-12-21 14:03:27 [45606] 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 => customer@msn.com F=<sales@domain.com> P=<sales@domain.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp S=242379 H=mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72]:25 I=[serverIP]:58058 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com" C="250  <10379473.175.1482328989231.JavaMail.GeoCust@CI352561> Queued mail for delivery" QT=7s DT=4s
2016-12-21 14:03:27 [45606] 1cJhUG-000BrX-A1 Completed QT=7s

2016-12-21 14:16:50 [46360] 1cJhhK-000C3k-2J <= returns@domain.com H=host81-149-113-123.in-addr.btopenworld.com ([192.168.1.111]) [81.149.113.123]:60254 I=[serverIP]:587 P=esmtpsa X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="mail.domain.com" A=dovecot_plain:returns@domain.com S=43042 M8S=8 id=e2db0fda-2106-d4f2-4d81-2d7804941999@domain.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <returns@domain.com> for customer@msn.com
2016-12-21 14:16:50 [46363] 1cJhhK-000C3k-2J SMTP connection outbound 1482329810 1cJhhK-000C3k-2J domain.com customer@msn.com
2016-12-21 14:16:52 [46363] 1cJhhK-000C3k-2J => customer@msn.com F=<returns@domain.com> P=<returns@domain.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp S=44390 H=mx3.hotmail.com [207.46.8.199]:25 I=[serverIP]:51020 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com" C="250  <e2db0fda-2106-d4f2-4d81-2d7804941999@domain.com> Queued mail for delivery" QT=2s DT=2s
2016-12-21 14:16:52 [46363] 1cJhhK-000C3k-2J Completed QT=2s

2016-12-22 11:06:55 [8716] 1cK1D4-0002Ga-IS <= customer@msn.com H=col004-omc1s15.hotmail.com [65.55.34.25]:55082 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=no S=34538 M8S=0 id=VI1PR0201MB2446426FDBAC1A995BBE40EE98920@VI1PR0201MB2446.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <customer@msn.com> for returns@domain.com
2016-12-22 11:06:55 [8732] 1cK1D4-0002Ga-IS => returns <returns@domain.com> F=<customer@msn.com> P=<customer@msn.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery S=35461 C="250 2.0.0 <returns@domain.com> 1CNcFs+zW1jEIQAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=1s DT=0s
2016-12-22 11:06:55 [8732] 1cK1D4-0002Ga-IS Completed QT=1s

2016-12-22 11:10:55 [8882] 1cK1Gx-0002JG-OV <= customer@msn.com H=snt004-omc1s25.hotmail.com [65.55.90.36]:65241 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=no S=7949 M8S=0 id=VI1PR0201MB244681EC850BEC4DE64B047998920@VI1PR0201MB2446.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com T="Re: Your Order - Invoice 260054" from <customer@msn.com> for sales@domain.com
2016-12-22 11:10:56 [8943] 1cK1Gx-0002JG-OV => sales <sales@domain.com> F=<customer@msn.com> P=<customer@msn.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery S=8233 C="250 2.0.0 <sales@domain.com> 0QQ/AMC0W1ioIgAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=1s DT=0s
2016-12-22 11:10:56 [8943] 1cK1Gx-0002JG-OV Completed QT=1s

2016-12-22 11:15:22 [9062] 1cK1LF-0002MA-Qs <= returns@domain.com H=host81-149-113-123.in-addr.btopenworld.com ([192.168.1.111]) [81.149.113.123]:50073 I=[serverIP]:587 P=esmtpsa X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="mail.domain.com" A=dovecot_plain:returns@domain.com S=56222 M8S=8 id=24bdd942-bc1f-f7f5-d395-3f93ee4a46b7@domain.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <returns@domain.com> for customer@msn.com
2016-12-22 11:15:22 [9076] 1cK1LF-0002MA-Qs SMTP connection outbound 1482405322 1cK1LF-0002MA-Qs domain.com customer@msn.com
2016-12-22 11:15:24 [9076] 1cK1LF-0002MA-Qs => customer@msn.com F=<returns@domain.com> P=<returns@domain.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp S=57760 H=mx4.hotmail.com [65.55.37.72]:25 I=[serverIP]:34286 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com" C="250  <24bdd942-bc1f-f7f5-d395-3f93ee4a46b7@domain.com> Queued mail for delivery" QT=3s DT=2s
2016-12-22 11:15:24 [9076] 1cK1LF-0002MA-Qs Completed QT=3s

    2016-12-22 11:26:25 [9775] 1cK1Vw-0002Xf-Ej <= customer@msn.com H=blu004-omc1s14.hotmail.com [65.55.116.25]:51410 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=no S=441530 M8S=0 id=VI1PR0201MB2446A6CA5BF70E2248FA4C5898920@VI1PR0201MB2446.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com T="Fotos" from <customer@msn.com> for returns@domain.com
    2016-12-22 11:26:25 [9841] 1cK1Vw-0002Xf-Ej => returns <returns@domain.com> F=<customer@msn.com> P=<customer@msn.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery S=447438 C="250 2.0.0 <returns@domain.com> kRBKOGG4W1gKJgAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=1s DT=0s
    2016-12-22 11:26:25 [9841] 1cK1Vw-0002Xf-Ej Completed QT=1s

    2016-12-22 11:57:29 [11153] 1cK200-0002tt-EQ <= customer@msn.com H=snt004-omc2s43.hotmail.com [65.54.61.94]:52729 I=[serverIP]:25 P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=no S=36499 M8S=0 id=VI1PR0201MB2446A0C922B4D03CFE5A50FE98920@VI1PR0201MB2446.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <customer@msn.com> for returns@domain.com
    2016-12-22 11:57:29 [11178] 1cK200-0002tt-EQ => returns <returns@domain.com> F=<customer@msn.com> P=<customer@msn.com> R=virtual_user T=dovecot_virtual_delivery S=37470 C="250 2.0.0 <returns@domain.com> qW8tBqm/W1h8KwAAT/Rueg Saved" QT=1s DT=0s
    2016-12-22 11:57:29 [11178] 1cK200-0002tt-EQ Completed QT=1s

    2016-12-22 12:35:23 [13281] 1cK2ag-0003SD-BA <= returns@domain.com H=host81-149-113-123.in-addr.btopenworld.com ([192.168.1.111]) [81.149.113.123]:51190 I=[serverIP]:587 P=esmtpsa X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="mail.domain.com" A=dovecot_plain:returns@domain.com S=68287 M8S=8 id=84a74168-5e2c-baef-a892-969e1b3886b4@domain.com T="Re: Contact Form" from <returns@domain.com> for customer@msn.com
    2016-12-22 12:35:23 [13312] 1cK2ag-0003SD-BA SMTP connection outbound 1482410123 1cK2ag-0003SD-BA domain.com customer@msn.com
    2016-12-22 12:35:25 [13312] 1cK2ag-0003SD-BA => customer@msn.com F=<returns@domain.com> P=<returns@domain.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp S=69978 H=mx2.hotmail.com [65.55.92.152]:25 I=[serverIP]:40378 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com" C="250  <84a74168-5e2c-baef-a892-969e1b3886b4@domain.com> Queued mail for delivery" QT=3s DT=2s
    2016-12-22 12:35:25 [13312] 1cK2ag-0003SD-BA Completed QT=3s
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `exigrep <ID> /var/log/exim_mainlog`, where <ID> is the message ID of one of the messages that's experiencing this issue.

Comment: I'll have to wait till it happens again as have no idea what the message IDs were at the moment it seems to happen between 1 and 2 months

Comment: You can also use the email address of the recipient to try and find a message ID. Exigrep will always group everything for a message together.

Comment: so it happened again today i also have message id's of the emails that vanished SENT folder of two accounts disappeared on the server

Comment: i should mention there are two users using this account with thunderbird

Comment: It looks like the sales and returns account is configured to ignore quotas as well as the 20 other accounts hosted on the server, only thing I can find is a Perl script in cpannel that runs backups but that runs daily and has no part to delete old mail but it does delete backups over a week old.